# Cannot convert string[] to char[]

Tags: c#

I have a textbox (textBoxA), I would do a split of the content, being single letters would put them in a char[] array (I will not use the lists). Here is the code I used, where I'm wrong?

```
char[] but = textBoxA.Text.Split("-".ToCharArray());
```

Comment: Well `Split` returns an array of strings, which isn't the same as an array of characters. What would you expect the result to be if the text is "AB-CD"? `Split` will return `{"AB", "CD"}` - what would you want `but` to be?

Comment: what do you have in the original string? Do you want to split it in two strings on the "-" and then put the result in... one char array? Do you want two char arrays maybe? Otherwise I'm confused on what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Maybe he wants char array with all the characters from string except the dash signs?

Comment: @Dialecticus: that would simply be something like `textBoxA.Text.Replace("-","").ToCharArray()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind the iteration, use Linq :) (`using System.Linq;`)

```
char[] but = textBoxA.Text.Split('-').Select(s => Convert.ToChar(s)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Note `textBoxA.Text.Split('-').SelectMany(s => s).ToArray()` is cleaner, IMO. But for that matter, @PaoloFalabella's suggestion of `textBoxA.Text.Replace("-","").ToCharArray()` would work just as well without Linq.

Answer (score 1):

Consider what you are doing. String.Split returns an array of Strings (string[]). If you assume that your input will only be individual characters, then you can use:

```
char[] values = textBoxA.Text.Split(new [] { '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(e => e[0]).ToArray( );
```

Comment: @p.s.w.g Good catch again!

Answer (score 0):

Array of `string` will be returned. See

```
string[] but = textBoxA.Text.Split("-".ToCharArray());
```

Also,

```
string[] but = textBoxA.Text.Split('-');
```

Comment: He wants a char array, not a string array.

Comment: @Robert IMO it's not at all clear what OP wants. The question is vague. This solution might be perfectly fine depending on the rest of the code, since we don't know *why* OP expects to assign the result to a `char[]`.

Comment: How? Cutting 2 Kilogram into 2 and asking for 100 gram each? @Robert

Comment: @p.s.w.g Yes, the question is meaning less. Why would `"-".ToCharArray()`?

Answer (score 0):

`Split`returns a string array. If you want a char array with each of the strings in order, you have to loop to the array returned by `Split`, convert each string individually and `Append` (or `Add`, can't recall the correct syntax), the char array that results from the conversion to your destination array.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use..

```
string s = "A-B-C-D-E";
char[] but = s.Split('-').Select(Convert.ToChar).ToArray();
```

...which is slightly shorter that one of the answers.